# Method invocation may produce java NullpointerException

Tags: android, android-cursor

I have a code:

```
public String getNameUpdateEvent(long id) {
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.rawQuery("select name from events WHERE _id=" + id + ";", null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    String updateNameEvent;
    updateNameEvent = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
    return updateNameEvent;
}
```

and I´m getting a warning

```
    Warning:(173, 45) Method invocation 'mCursor.getColumnIndex("name")' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'
```

How i can fix it pls?

Comment: why not just mCursor.getString(1);

Comment: Here's a thought, what would happen if `mCursor` is null and you make the call `mCursor.getColumnIndex("name")`?

Comment: I have provided an anwer about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46519388/method-invocation-may-produce-nullpointerexception-retrofit-body/46519442

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your cursor can not be `null`, it will always have any value. But cursor can be empty, so you should firstly go to first row in cursor with method `moveToFirst()`, and if it returns `true` - it means, that cursor has at least one row, so you can do with it all you want, if it returns `false` - it means, that there is nothing for your query, so you have not any rows to get data from. Your code should look like this:

```
public String getNameUpdateEvent(long id) {
    Cursor mCursor =
        db.rawQuery("select name from events WHERE _id=" + id + ";", null);

    String updateNameEvent = null;
    if (mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        updateNameEvent = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
    }
    return updateNameEvent;
}
```

Comment: Won't this still produce the same warning: `Warning:(173, 45) Method invocation 'mCursor.getColumnIndex("name")' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'`

Comment: I have edited my answer. I'm not sure if rawQuery can return null value. I thought that can't, so warning is IDE bug. But if can - then my. In any case it should have checking if cursor have values I think.

Comment: ok, now the Orest edited solution is working, just i needeed to initialize String updateNameEvent = null; . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:  Since you are hard coding SQL, why not hard code the index

```
 updateNameEvent = mCursor.getString(0);
```

Solution 2:

```
try{
    updateNameEvent = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
}catch(IllegalArgumentException ie){
    updateNameEvent = 0; 
}
```

getColumnIndexOrThrow method will throw IllegalArgumentException if column don't exists.

Solution 1 is faster and simple.

Comment: why change it around when he could just catch a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: with NullPointer, you still need to check for return -1