# Method invocation may produce NullPointerException Retrofit Body

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2 for get response from my API and store its value in my constant like below

```
if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    constant.banner_on = response.body().getBanner_on();
                    constant.int_on = response.body().getInt_on();
                    constant.int_click = response.body().getInt_click();
                }
```

It's giving me warning on all three like below

> Method invocation getBanner_on may produce java.lang.nullPointerException

I am confused and unable to resolve this warning. Let me know if someone can help me to come out from this.

Comment: This is giving a warning because the response may be null, so for safe side Android Studio gives warning, for not getting the exception you can assert `response!=null` and the continue on.

Comment: Yes, this may be possible the response may be null so wrap the code into a if statement it is good to save your app by `NullPointerExecption` as in your previous question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should one use Objects.requireNonNull()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45632920/why-should-one-use-objects-requirenonnull)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is just a warning as it will never be null if the response is successful. You can ignore it or wrap around `if(response.body() != null)` to remove the warning.

```
Ads ads = response.body();
if(ads != null){
    constant.banner_on = ads.getBanner_on();
    // and so on.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `if` is great but there is only one line, much cleaner way is:

```
constant.banner_on = ads != null ? ads.getBanner_on() : null;
```

If you are using [Java 8, you can do a **assertion**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html) before assignment:

```
Ads ads = response.body();
assert ads != null;
constant.banner_on = ads.getBanner_on();
```

Another way to do this is using **`Objects.requireNonNull()`** before assignment:

```
constant.banner_on = Objects.requireNonNull(ads.getBanner_on());
```

That is actually designed primarily for param validation. Source code comment:

```
/**
     * Checks that the specified object reference is not {@code null}. This
     * method is designed primarily for doing parameter validation in methods
     * and constructors, as demonstrated below:
     * <blockquote><pre>
     * public Foo(Bar bar) {
     *     this.bar = Objects.requireNonNull(bar);
     * }
     * </pre></blockquote>
     *
```

One great [SO answer about this is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45632920/why-should-one-use-objects-requirenonnull). Also [read this to get understanding why we need to explicitly check.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928556/why-explicitly-throw-a-nullpointerexception-rather-than-letting-it-happen-natura).

Answer (score 2):

Just use this `null` pointer check.

```
If(response != null && response.isSuccessfull())
{

// body

}
```

Comment: @priya i am not sure about this, but can you check null pointer for response.getBody() as well?   That is if (response !=null && respone.getBody() ! =Null) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

Its a good habit to before assigning any value from response handle `null pointer exception` to prevent some of exception. And you can also use `try` and `catch` to handle other exceptions.

```
 if(response.isSuccessful()) {
    try {
         if(response.body() != null){
                constant.banner_on = response.body().getBanner_on();
                constant.int_on = response.body().getInt_on();
                constant.int_click = response.body().getInt_click();
           }
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
```